# Getting data from log file

Tags: log-files, grep

I'd like to get the memory usage from the following log entries.  It's the number right after 200 for the URL.  I'd like to get a  list of highest memory usage first, like top 10.  I think I'd use grep for this, right?

```
178.0.140.206 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:09 -0400] "GET /image/promo/terran-88x31.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 15227 0 -
79.66.101.95 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:09 -0400] "GET /strategy/article/view/?id=608 HTTP/1.1" 200 8456 0 4980736
79.66.101.95 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:10 -0400] "GET /lib/php/min/?f=lib/css/yui/2.7.0.css,lib/css/base.css,lib/css/ux/rating.css,lib/css/page/strategy.css,lib/css/page/article.css,lib/css/page/strategy/article.css HTTP/1.1" 200 8118 0 1835008
79.66.101.95 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:11 -0400] "GET /image/logo-text.png HTTP/1.1" 200 9444 0 -
79.66.101.95 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:11 -0400] "GET /image/s.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 43 0 -
79.66.101.95 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:11 -0400] "GET /image/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17722 0 -
79.66.101.95 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:13 -0400] "GET /lib/php/min/?f=lib/js/ext/3.0-core.js,lib/js/global.js,lib/js/ext/ux/rating.js,lib/js/page/article.js HTTP/1.1" 200 32919 0 1310720
79.66.101.95 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:16 -0400] "GET /lib/css/resource/body-bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 467 0 -
79.66.101.95 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:16 -0400] "GET /lib/css/resource/foot-bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 119 0 -
79.66.101.95 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:16 -0400] "GET /lib/css/resource/search-bg-sprite.png HTTP/1.1" 200 280 0 -
190.213.177.71 - - [05/Nov/2010:16:46:16 -0400] "GET /images/banner/dark-templar_firefox.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 2827 0 1572864
```

Comment: grep | awk/sed | sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the URL being access as well (you can tweak the `awk` print statement as needed to get more fields):

```
awk '{ print $10,$7 }' PATH_TO_LOG_FILE | sort -k1 -rn | head -n10
```

To use it for only a specific HTTP code (in this case, 200):

```
awk '{ if($9=="200") {print $10,$7} }' PATH_TO_LOG_FILE | sort -k1 -rn | head -n10
```

Or use a regex to check for multiple error codes:

```
awk '{ if($9~"^200|403|404$") {print $10,$7} }' PATH_TO_LOG_FILE | sort -k1 -rn | head -n10
```

If this is something you plan on running repeatedly, consider looking into a CustomLog.

Comment: Your regex should be `"^(200|403|404)$"`. The default for `sort` is `-k1` so you could omit that unless you meant to do `-k1,1`.

Comment: Because we're not matching the HTTP return code for use, there's no need to group it.  As for the `sort`, you're absolutely right--although in this case, I prefer to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I know that these numbers reflect the returned content size. Anyway, you can get the needed column (after 200) using this commnad:

```
grep "1.1\" 200 " logfile | awk {'print $10'} | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

Comment: You should do `sort -nr` for a numeric sort and some versions of `head` require `-n`: `head -n 10`

Comment: It should be ok now!